# XY Tolerance settings of sDNA

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sdna

As I ran several tools of sDNA I noticed these lines in every error report:

ERROR: Unable to obtain XYTolerance for near miss connection check
ERROR:   Either add a spatial reference to the feature class,
ERROR:   or override XYTolerance in the script environment settings.

At first I thought I have found where the mistake lies and filled the XY tolerance as the recommended value, yet everything remained the same. 
(The projected coordinate system of this file is WGS_1984_EASE_Grid_Global, also in meters, so the two should be compatible, I guess?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Setting XYTolerance in the environment settings *should* work but doesn't - there is a bug I'm not sure whether with sDNA or ArcMap.

If your data is a feature class in a gdb it will have a tolerance setting which can be found by right-clicking the class in the catalog and choosing properties. sDNA will respect the tolerance settings of gdb feature classes. Other formats such as shapefiles do not contain tolerance information.

So, to override either of these you can use the `xytolerance` keyword in sDNA advanced config. For many sDNA tools a box lablleded "Advanced Configuration" appears at the bottom of the dialog; putting `xytolerance=0.0001` in here will set it to 0.1mm (so long as your coordinate system is in metres, as you say it is). In the case of sDNA Prepare this is a commonly used function so instead there is a box labelled "Custom XY Tolerance" - just put 0.0001 in that box for the same effect.